# If Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I have a custom taxonomy set for my posts, called `$type`.  I would like to echo within the standard WordPress while loop, if the `$type == 'roast'`.

```
<?php $number = 1; ?>
<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $type = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'type', '' );
    echo $type;                         
    if ($type == "roast") { ?>
        <li><?php echo $number . '. '; $number++;?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <span><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'rating', '' ); ?></span>
            <span><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'price', '' ); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php } 
if (in_array('roast', $type)) { echo "hello"; }
?>
```

I first echo out `$type`, as a test, and this does echo 'roast'.

Yet my if statement, and later attempt at using `in_array`, do not echo as expected.

Can anyone kindly advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what goes wrong with the if statement?

Comment: Nothing displays.  If I put in a basic <?php echo "hello"; ?> then it doesn't even echo 'hello'.

Comment: "*Yet my if statement, and later attempt at using in_array, do not echo as expected." — `$type` is not an `array` because [`get_the_term_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) doesn't return an `array`.

Answer (score 2):

`get_the_term_list()` returns a string of HTML for the list of taxonomy terms on the given post. Without giving values in the optional arguments it would look like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/type/roast/" rel="tag">Roast</a> <a href="http://example.com/type/type2/" rel="tag">Type 2</a>
```

So `$type == 'roast'` would not be true because the value isn't anything close to `'roast'`.

Even if it returned an array like `array( 'roast' )` it wouldn't be true because `'roast'` does not equal `array( 'roast' )`.

If you want to check if a post has a given term in a taxonomy, use the [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) function:

```
if ( has_term( 'roast', 'type' ) ) {

}
```